# How to refer a formula field in vf page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a formula field in account object as "CreationOrigin" which contains formula as `TEXT(User.UserType__c)`. I need to display this value in my VF Page. IN what way can i get this done ? Anyone of you provide me the code for this would be grateful.

UserType is a picklist value.

Comment: Have you tried anything? are you facing any issue?

Answer (score 2):

Simple as any other field

```
<apex:outPutField value="{!Account.CreationOrigin__c}"/>
```

Did you do any reading or any work on this yourself? This is one of the most basic aspects of visual force so you will want to understand the concepts here.

Also, I am not sure your formula will work as there us no user field on the Account. You could probably use something like `Owner.UserType__c`

Answer (score 0):

You can use any formula field in VF pages using outputfield tag.

```
<apex:outPutField value="{!Account.CreationOrigin__c}"/>
```

You can't use it in inputfield as it is a formula field.